# I am new to MVC or you can say new to OOPS. Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of both the lines?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

.Where(m=> m.Depatment.Name =="")

.Where(m => m.JobTitle.Name == "Administrator")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where(m=> m.Depatment.Name =="")

this line means it will take only which department is blank or string.Empty;

```
.Where(m => m.JobTitle.Name == "Administrator")
```

this line is similar to the first one only change is model property in the first one you have taken department and in this you have taken JobTitle
basically this line means it will take only which jobTitle have a name is Administrator

Comment: Thank you can you please tell me if I want to add many departments in this line?     Where(m=> m.Depatment.Name =="") actually all department has one Administrator and I want to send a message to all the administrator but the message is going only one department's administrator.

Comment: Where(m=> m.Depatment.Name.contain("BE") || m.Depatment.Name.contain("BTec")); this the query you can apply into where condition

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I have almost 50 departments is there any query I can write for all because putting 50 will be too much

Comment: do you need all departments? if Yes then why you need to where condition on it

Comment: give me your full liqu query?

Comment: I am trying to post code but it is saying too long characters how can I give you?

Comment: If you need to all department then remove where clause form query

Answer (score 1):

`Where` is from LINQ (`System.Linq`), which is short for "Language-Integrated Query". LINQ provides a set of methods that allow you build dynamic queries on basically any object structure. ORMs like Entity Framework support LINQ, and use it to build actual SQL queries behind the scenes, but you can use LINQ anywhere, really, not just for database access.

The parameter to something like `Where` is a lambda expression. The type is actually `Func<TSource, bool>`, which simply means it's a function that takes a generic type and returns a bool. In a lambda, the left side of the `=>` is the parameter(s) to the lambda, while the right side is the return value of the lambda. So, both of these have a parameter, `m`, and include an expression that evaluates to a boolean. The actual value that's passed to the parameter is obviously the entity type you're working with, i.e. the object you're querying. In practical terms, any objects where the expression evaluates to `true` will be returned, while any that evaluate to `false` will be excluded. The result will be an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, where `TSource` is your entity type. In other words, it's going to return a list of all the entities that match.

Based on that, the first expression will return any entities where the related `Department`'s `Name` property is an empty string. The second expression, meanwhile, will return all the entities where the related `JobTile`'s `Name` property is equal to `"Administrator"`.